# Query 'optimizing' state is taking too long

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have a MySQL 5.6 on Amazon RDS that I'm using for testing some data archiving scripts. I'm removing oldest data based on a "updated_date" column and index. Curiously, after removing a few million rows, my script gets stuck on the initial query it does for determining data bounds.

I run a query like this:

```
SELECT min(updated_date) as oldest, max(updated_date) AS newest FROM `order`;
```

The `explain` command on this query shows:

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Select tables optimized away'
```

So, it's supposed to hit the index and run almost instantly, and it did when the testing started, but now, after millions of rows were removed, it gets stuck in the 'optimizing' state for several minutes.

The script is the only thing running on the database.

Any ideas on what's wrong with it? Am I supposed to do something when removing lots of rows like that? Do I have to run `optimize table`, even though I'm not using `delete quick`?

**Update #1**

The result from `show table status like 'order'`:

```
Name,Engine,Version,Row_format,Rows,Avg_row_length,Data_length,Max_data_length,Index_length,Data_free,Auto_increment,Create_time,Update_time,Check_time,Collation,Checksum,Create_options,Comment
order,InnoDB,10,Compact,568037197,280,159252496384,0,180806041600,37692112896,4052226884,"2015-01-26 17:27:20",NULL,NULL,utf8_general_ci,NULL,,
```

The result from `select count(*) from order` is 618376777 rows.

Unfortunately, I can't post the whole schema here, but where it bears on the issue, the result from `show create table order` is:

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  // 31 data columns here
  `updated_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),       
  KEY `ix_order_updated_date` (`updated_date`),
  // 9 indexes here
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4052226884 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Update #2**

By separating the min() and max() calls in two queries, I noticed only the min() query is affected. The max() returns almost immediately, so it looks like the min() is traversing the index for all index entries that existed but are now empty. Is there any way to prevent that from happening other than rebuilding the index?

**Update #3**

RickJames nailed the problem with the hint about change buffering, but disabling it entirely compromises performance for all inserts, deletes and updates. Eventually, I figured out the time it took to flush the changing buffer was reasonable with the production server, so problem solved for me, but if you run into the same issue with a low-end server with magnetic storage, good luck with it.

Comment: I assume your table's engine is InnoDB. Rune the following three statements please: `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'order'` and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE order`

Comment: @JehadKeriaki yes, InnoDB. Check my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT min(updated_date) as oldest, max(updated_date) AS newest FROM `order`;
```

is well optimized *if* you have `INDEX(updated_date)` (which you do).  It will do two probes.  No need for two queries, etc.

The `EXPLAIN` said 'optimized away' because it could see that it did not need to do any work.

I checked with a similar table, then checked the `Handler%` STATUS values -- `Handler_read_first` and `Handler_read_last` incremented by 1 each.  This is indicative of optimizing `MIN` and `MAX`.

Do not use `OPTIMIZE TABLE` it is (usually) a long wast of time.

It is a huge table.

DELETEing a million rows will queue up a lot of stuff, especially because of 10 secondary indexes.  I'll bet that when you asked for MAX and MIN, it had to finish up all the pending index updates.

If that is the case, none of the suggestions will really solve the problem.  Chunking the deletes (which is a good idea anyway) might have "hidden" the problem by slowing down the delete task.  As @eroomydna says, the undo logs must have been huge.

On what basis are you DELETEing?  If it is "purge all records older than X", then this is a cure:  `PARTITION BY RANGE(...)` on the date (to use for purging) and `DROP PARTITION` to jetison old rows.  This is also much cleaner (in the sense of OPTIMIZEing to defragment) than DELETEing.

Rolando, `ANALYZE TABLE` will recalc the stats "instantly".  `OPTIMIZE TABLE` rebuilds (and ANALYZEs) the table but takes forever on this sized table.

Potentially valid is to copy over the useful rows, a la Rolando's #4.  But only if you are jettisoning "most" of the table.  I suggest that is not the case here -- "deleting a few million rows" out of 618M.

10 secondary keys is a lot.  Would you care to show them; we may have suggestions on pruning the list.  For this sized table, it is costly to maintain that many.

**Edit** -- "Change buffering"

I believe what I have described is called change buffering for DELETEs.  More discussion:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-performance-change_buffering.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-performance-change_buffering.html

You could try `innodb_change_buffering = none`.

Comment: The rows are deleted by primary key. Unfortunately, partitioning is not an option. You say it probably had to finish up all the pending index updates, but if that is the case, subsequent queries should be faster, right? I just noticed even an explain takes a long time to run, so it looks like you're right. Is there any way for me to force the index update immediately after deleting the chunk?

Comment: This sounds like the answer:  Do _that_ after each chunk.  Also, each chunk should be a separate transaction (eg, have autocommit=1).  Assuming you are not replicating, I would set the chunk size at, say, 1000 rows.  [My blog discusses deleting in chunks.](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig)

Comment: That seems to be working, the query for min(updated_date) no longer takes several minutes to complete after a long data archiving session, but it still takes an average 3s while initially it would return in a few ms, like the max(updated_date) query. Any idea on what else might be wrong?

Comment: see edit.  Please report back if you try `innodb_change_buffering = none`; I would be interested to hear the performance change.

Comment: I'm creating a new RDS instance to repeat the tests with a fresh snapshot. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: With 'none' the delete operations become too slow. It takes over 25s to delete a 1k chunk. I couldn't even delete enough rows to check if the min() delay becomes noticeable. I'm now experimenting with 'purges', which buffers only the physical deletion and doesn't compromise delete performance, and I'll check If the min() isn't slower after removing a few million rows.

Comment: How often do you need to delete a million rows?  Suggest setting up a loop that (1) finds a chunk, (2) deletes it, (3) loop.  Then let that run forever.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but that's not the problem. The problem is how the index affects other queries. Anyway, the 'purges' value doesn't work either. After deleting 6 million rows the min(id) query is taking 1s. I'll check how long it takes to catch up while idle. I wonder how pt-archiver works and how it solves the same problem, if it does.

Comment: Oops; step "(2) is delete the chunk _and_ do select min(id)".  In theory that will force the flush of the change buffer.  If the min() is too slow, decrease the chunk size.

Comment: I tried both, min(id) or min(updated_date), it makes no difference. MySQL docs says the server flushes the buffer when idle or during a slow shutdown . I can't change the innodb_fast_shutdown on Amazon RDS, so the last resort is checking how long it takes to do it while idle.

Comment: The test server, with magnetic disk, took 3 days of idle time to flush all changes from 14M deleted rows. I decided to test again with a server identical to our production, with more RAM and provisioned IOPS, and it took less than one hour. Not perfect, but good enough.

Answer (score 1):

The best performing way to delete a lot of data is to chunk your activity. There are tools to complete this such as pt-archive and oak-chunk-update. This avoids the build up of undo and performance issues.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that's not the issue.

Comment: Well, it may happen to help the problem.

Answer (score 1):

## SUGGESTION #1

Perhaps you can retrieve the min and max date as separate queries

```
SELECT updated_date INTO @oldest_updated_date
FROM `order` ORDER BY updated_date LIMIT 1;
SELECT updated_date INTO @newest_updated_date
FROM `order` ORDER BY updated_date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This will traverse the index one one key per query

## SUGGESTION #2

You should shrink the table after mass deletes.

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE `order`;
```

## SUGGESTION #3

After performing the mass delete, the index statistics need to be recalculated. `OPTIMIZE TABLE` does it for youm but you can do a as a separate step, like this:

```
ANALYZE TABLE `order`;
```

## SUGGESTION #4

Perhaps recreate the table from a start date. For example, to keep the last 30 days, do this:

```
SET @TimeGapToKeep = NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;
ALTER TABLE `order` RENAME `old_order`;
CREATE TABLE `new_order` LIKE `old_order`;
INSERT INTO `new_order` SELECT * FROM `old_order`
WHERE updated_date >= @TimeGapToKeep;
ALTER TABLE `new_order` RENAME `order`;
ANALYZE TABLE `order`;
```

Comment: #1 is an interesting idea, but it took the same amount of time for the min value. Then I noticed it returned almost instantly for the max value. Since I'm deleting rows from the beginning of the index, it looks like something wrong with the index after the deletion. I'd prefer to avoid an optimize table because a copy of a table this size will take hours or days. Unfortunately, #4 is not an option.

Comment: I disagree with all 4...  #1 -- No, unnecessary; #2 -- this was less than 1% delete, and costs more than it is worth; #3 -- For just recalculating stats, use `ANALYZE`, not `OPTIMIZE`; #4 -- again, not practical since <1%.